# What does this "employed as" apply to?

Tags: meaning

> There are 2 women and 1 guy employed as receptionists at the hotel.

In the example above, does "employed as" apply to both women and guy, or just a guy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sentences like this can be ambiguous. For example an ambiguous sentence could be.

> There are two men and two women employed as receptionists.

It could be that all four are receptions or possibly only the two women. Without further context I would assume that the man is also a receptionist but the sentence is ambiguous.

On the other hand

> There are two women and one man employed as receptionist**s**.

is not ambiguous, because the word "receptionists" is plural, so must refer to the group of three people, and not just the one man.  So the women are certainly also receptionists.